# Accesibilidad web: combinación de teclas que suplen la acción de un botón

Tags: accesibilidad

me ha surgido una ***duda en cuanto a accesibilidad***.

Tengo una aplicación en *ReactJs*, con dos pantallas. Existe un botón para moverse entre ellas que contiene una imagen.

El botón de tipo *button* por lo que se puede seleccionar con la tecla "tab". La imagen / icono interior tiene atributos `alt` y `title` descriptivos.

Hasta aquí, creo que todo correcto.

He añadido la posibilidad de cambiar entre pantallas con una combinación de teclas. Es decir esta combinación hace lo mismo que el botón. *Realmente el común de los mortales desconoce que esta opción existe, pero hace el cambio de pantalla más cómodo...* y la pregunta:

**¿Hay alguna forma de indicar a los *screenreaders* y dispositivos similares que hay una combinación de teclas que puede usarse para activar un botón?**

Answer (score 1):

### El atributo aria-keyshortcuts

es muy sencillo añadir una descripción de teclado a un elemento en HTML. Lo único que tienes que hacer es esto:

```
<button aria-keyshortcuts="Tecla+Tecla" >Menú</button>
```

El código anterior hará que un lector de pantalla lea esa descripción que hallas puesto como valor del atributo aria.
ejemplo:

```
<button aria-keyshortcuts="Ctrl+b" >Menú</button>   
<button aria-keyshortcuts="Alt+b" >Menú</button>
```

Etc.
Espero haber ayudado, saludos.

Comment: Gracias, sí. Me has ayudado. Añado un enlace a doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/ariaKeyShortcuts